# Question on the implication of Lebesgue integration in Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, path-integral, topology, action

Suppose I have two Riemannian manifolds in two dimensions, a 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and a disk $\mathbb{D}$. I would like to know whether there is a redundancy in Hawking's path integral approach to quantum gravity. Indeed, classically for two metrics $g_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ and $g_{\mathbb{D}}$, the two actions are:
\begin{align}
S[g_{\mathbb{S}^2}] =& \int_{\mathbb{S}^2} d^2x \sqrt{g}\,R+\underbrace{2\int_{\partial \mathbb{S^2}} dx \sqrt{\gamma} K}_{\equiv 0} \tag{1}
\\
S[g_{\mathbb{D}}] =& \int_\mathbb{D} d^2x \sqrt{g}\,R+2\int_{\mathbb{S^1}} dx \sqrt{\gamma} K \tag{2}
\end{align}
Classically the two are completely different. Now consider $\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{\text{pt}\}$ instead of $\mathbb{S}^2$ ($\text{pt}$ is the north pole for example). Since the integrals are Lebesgue ones, we have the following:
\begin{equation}
S[g_{\mathbb{S}^2}] \stackrel{!}{=} S[g_{\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{\text{pt}\}}] \tag{3}
\end{equation}
But $\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{\text{pt}\} \stackrel{\text{homeo}}{\simeq} \mathbb{D}$, which means we can always find a new metric $g'_{\mathbb{D}} = g_{\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{\text{pt}\}}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
S[g_{\mathbb{S}^2}] = S[g'_{\mathbb{D}}] \tag{4}
\end{equation}
And equivalently one can find $g'_{\mathbb{S}^2\setminus \{\text{pt}\}} = g_{\mathbb{D}}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
S[g'_{\mathbb{S}^2}] = S[g_{\mathbb{D}}] \tag{5}
\end{equation}
**Question:**

Does this mean that when performing the functional integral${}^1$ over the metrics, these ones will eventually coincide for two topologically different surfaces (by virtue of the fact that the action integral is a Lebesgue one)? This would mean that the 2-sphere and the disk are "degenerate" because they give the same factor $e^{-S}$.

---

${}^1$ by this *do not* mean the wild integral over the metrics in the superspace, but rather an integration over smooth metrics.

Comment: Equation (3) is worrying me. I might be wrong, but is it true that even for the case $S^2- \{pt\}$, the boundary integral will vanish? The bulk term should be the same though

Comment: @KP99 Thank you for your comment. I think the boundary term vanishes in this case because $\int_{\partial (\mathbb{S}\setminus \{\text{pt}\})} = \int_{\partial \{\text{pt}\}}$, which is zero. But maybe I am wrong and missing something obvious...

Comment: It seems a once punctured sphere will still have no boundary (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/773444). I was wondering if I could consider the subset $S^2- U$ ( where $U$ is some neighborhood containing the north pole N), calculate the boundary integral and then shrink $U$ upto N (question is whether this can be done in an appropriate sense). Then ,the equality (3) and therefore the identifications (4) and (5) won't arise

Comment: @KP99 Thank you for the link. This one talks about the once puncture, but what about a twice puncture (North and South)?

Comment: @KP99 The idea for the limiting procedure sounds reasonable. Is your idea that the $\sqrt{\gamma}$ will do the work for us in not letting the boundary integral vanish in the limit? I think this way we might get a nice example that (3) does not hold.

Comment: It's best to think in terms of stereographic projection. The northpole corresponds to the point at infinity while southpole will get mapped to the origin. Thus $S^2-\{ N,S\} \cong R^2-\{0\}$ . @kricheli I'm not an expert but I feel that this issue here has to do with the basics of continuity and convergence associated to lebesgue integrable functions (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1477452)